ToolbarItem creates a very noticeable gap between buttons
Here's the toolbar code:
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
        LanguageButtonView(buttonBackgroundColor: .clear)
            .environmentObject(appManager)
    }
}

Here's the LanguageButtonView:
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Button {
            self.hideKeyboard()
                appManager.language = .th
                LocalizeManager.setLanguage(langCode: .th)
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(appManager.language == .th ? colorPalette.color(style: .color434B24) : Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 32)

                    Text("common_th".localized(appManager.language.rawValue))
                    .foregroundColor(appManager.language == .th ? .white : colorPalette.color(style: .color434B24))
                    .font(fontSet.font(style: .header1))
            }
        }

        Button {
            self.hideKeyboard()
                appManager.language = .en
                LocalizeManager.setLanguage(langCode: .en)
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(appManager.language == .en ? colorPalette.color(style: .color434B24) : Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 32)

                    Text("common_en".localized(appManager.language.rawValue))
                    .foregroundColor(appManager.language == .en ? .white : colorPalette.color(style: .color434B24))
                    .font(fontSet.font(style: .header1))
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 80, height: 32)
        .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .stroke(colorPalette.color(style: .color434B24), lineWidth: 1)
                )

}

I've tested by using the same component at the top of my VStack and in the toolbar. The result below (in the VStack) is what I intended. How do I workaround this?
(The targeted version is iOS 14)

It worked normally with just one button, but it needs to be 2. I don't understand what's happening here or how to prevent it.
It seems to only happen to the Right view. The right button itself is in the right position.
Here's the minimal producible example of LanguageButtonView
struct LanguageButtonView: View {
    var buttonBackgroundColor: Color
    var borderColor: Color = .white
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                self.hideKeyboard()
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.clear)
                        .cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 32)
                    
                    Text("TH")
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                self.hideKeyboard()
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 32)
                    
                    Text("EN")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 80, height: 32)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .stroke(Color(hex: "434B24"), lineWidth: 1)
        )
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    LanguageButtonView(buttonBackgroundColor: .blue)
        .environmentObject(AppManager())
}



Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

I've edited the original post to show a minimal reproducible example now. You can use this code in any View

It seems to only happen to the Right view. The right button itself is in the right position.

Try using  .onTapGesture instead of buttons

I would just use a Picker(...).pickerStyle(.segmented) instead.
In both cases, the Picker and the Button labels, there are limitations
on what can be done to style them.

This may be an issue of the button style. You are setting a frame size for the HStack and then expecting that the button labels will not only expand to fill the available space but also contract if the buttons would normally take more space. This is not working.
I would suggest defining your own ButtonStyle. Here is an example that shows it working this way:
struct ToolbarButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let color: Color
    let roundedEdges: Edge.Set
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 40, minHeight: 32)
            .background(
                color
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
                    .background(color.padding(roundedEdges, 20))
            )
    }
}

struct LanguageButtonView: View {
    var buttonBackgroundColor: Color
    var borderColor: Color = .white

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button("TH") {
//                self.hideKeyboard()
            }
            .buttonStyle(ToolbarButtonStyle(color: .yellow, roundedEdges: .leading))
            Button("EN") {
//                self.hideKeyboard()
            }
            .buttonStyle(ToolbarButtonStyle(color: .orange, roundedEdges: .trailing))
        }
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .stroke(Color(hex: "434B24"), lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

You were using some kind of extension to round certain corners of the rectangle. In the example above I have used a simple technique that should work with iOS 14.

